# Store and retrieve encrypted values in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, encryption

I have an EditText `e` and I'm encrypting the value of its content using this method

```
byte[] encodeData(byte[] key, byte[] data)
{
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Cryptography", e.getMessage());
    }
    return new byte[0];
}
```

I'm just calling this method as

```
byte[] encoded = encodeData(key, e.getText.toString());
```

And storing the value in SQLiteDatabse as

```
SQLiteDatabase sd = db.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("COL_NAME", encoded);
```

And then retrieving it using below function

```
byte[] decodeData(byte[] key, byte[] data)
{
    try {
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("Cryptography", e.getMessage());
    }
    return new byte[0];
}
```

and calling it as

```
SQLiteDatabase sd = db.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cur = sd.rawQuery("select * from TABLE_NAME", null);
if(cur.moveToNext()) {
    byte[] decoded = decodeData(key, cur.getBlob(0));
}
```

But when I'm setting the value of EditText as this value, then it is showing blank.

```
e.setText(new String(decoded));
```

Though if I store the data without encryption, it works fine!

Comment: read the log becuase now it seems like you are doing `e.setText(new String(new byte[0]));` ... also `cur.getBlob(0)` are you sure that blob column is a first column?

Comment: ohh yes.... I'm getting exception in the decodeData method and it's saying `last block incomplete in decryption`

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are handling Cursor in the wrong way.

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
  while(!c.isAfterLast()) { // If you use c.moveToNext() here, you will bypass the first row, which is WRONG
    ...
    c.moveToNext();
  } 
}
```

Comment: rawQuery returns cursor in before first state ... it is pretty valid to use moveToNext only if you wana get only first row